# Property .Value not available for DatePicker?

Tags: c#, wpf, date, datepicker

It might be a beginners question, but I want to get the date (yyyy-mm-dd) from a datepicker field in WPF Application, C#. I do know that I have to save the date with a DateTime method, because I'm going to insert this into a database.

Everywhere I look on the internet they say use the .Value property, but if I type the .Value property after the DatePicker it does not reconize the property.

Does someone know how fix this or have an alternative way to get the date out of the datepicker?

```
private void btnPlanGP_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            string grandPrixNaam = naamGPTextBox.Text;
            DateTime datumGP = new DateTime();
            datumGP = datumDatePicker.Value;
            int aantalRondes = Convert.ToInt32(aantalRondesTextBox.Text);
            string naamBaan = naamBaanComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
            int coureurID = Convert.ToInt32(coureurIDComboBox.SelectedItem);
            int gastID = Convert.ToInt32(gastIDComboBox.SelectedItem);

            try
            {
                formule1DataSetGrandPrixTableAdapter.Insert(grandPrixNaam, datumGP, naamBaan, aantalRondes, coureurID, gastID);
                formule1DataSetGrandPrixTableAdapter.Fill(formule1DataSet.GrandPrix);
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(ex));
        }
    }
```

Comment: show your code.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.selecteddate(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: In WPF, it's called `SelectedDate`, not `Value`. The Windows Forms control is called `DateTimePicker` and has a `Value` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in `DatePicker` control in WPF has a [SelectedDate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.selecteddate(v=vs.110).aspx) that returns a DateTime?. Try this:

```
string grandPrixNaam = naamGPTextBox.Text;
DateTime datumGP = datumDatePicker.SelectedDate.HasValue ? datumDatePicker.SelectedDate.Value : default(DateTime);
int aantalRondes = Convert.ToInt32(aantalRondesTextBox.Text);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the anwer from Ed Plunkett.
WPF does indeed not have the .Value property. I changed it to .SelectedDate and this worked.

```
DateTime? datumGP = new DateTime();
datumGP = datumDatePicker.SelectedDate;
```

Comment: Do you want me to remove my answer?

Comment: @mm8 You can leave it there. Maybe someone will prefer your answer.

Comment: So why did you write another one?

Comment: Because it's shorter

Comment: And a lot less informative. And why are you creating a new DateTime()? Makes no sense. By the way, the additional lines of code in my answer is from your code. I don't really understand why you would basically copy the answer from someone who is trying to help you. But maybe that's just me...